# Nodejs Nodemailer with Mailcow Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am having problem getting my nodejs nodemailer to work. I don't know exactly where I made a mistake because I followed the example on the nodemail github page.
As mailserver interface I use mailcow.
I tried the default ports from Mailcow here, also with secureConnection false but it made no difference.

My Code:

```
              var usermail = "test@mydomain.com"
              var transp = mail.createTransport("SMTP",{
                    host: "mail.mydomain.com",
                    port: 587,
                    secureConnection: true,
                    auth: {
                        user: process.env.email,
                        pass: process.env.passwd
                    }
                })

                transp.sendMail({
                    to: usermail,
                    subject: "test",
                    text: "test" 
                },    
                function(err,response){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(response);
                });
```

My Errorcode:

```
0|app  | TypeError: Cannot create property 'mailer' on string 'SMTP'
0|app  |     at new Mail (/home/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:45:33)
0|app  |     at Object.module.exports.createTransport (/home/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js:53:14)
0|app  |     at /home/routes/system.js:876:35
0|app  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Would be great if someone helps me there times what exactly I did wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you, that it can not handle 'SMTP' as a parameter.
According to the [Documentation](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/), you do not need to specify "SMTP", because it expects an object with the configuration as the first paramter:

```
 var transp = mail.createTransport({
                host: "mail.mydomain.com",
                port: 587,
                secureConnection: true,
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.email,
                    pass: process.env.passwd
                }
            })
```

Comment: It looks like the Devs behind nodemailer shortly changed the signature of `createTransport`. That is maybe the reason why the example is not up to date.